# Update the software in a EC2 instance with CloudFormation update process

Tags: update, amazon-cloudformation

I wonder if there's any way to update the software inside the instance. I mean, I've a software running in EC2, I deploy the software with a CF template. That template has a parameter with the software version.

I've configured cfn-hup with:

```
'/etc/cfn/cfn-hup.conf':
    content: !Sub |
        [main]
        stack=${AWS::StackId}
        region=${AWS::Region}
        verbose=true
        interval=5
    mode: '000400'
    owner: root
    group: root
'/etc/cfn/hooks.d/cfn-auto-reloader.conf':
    content: !Sub |
        [cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
        triggers=post.update
        path=Resources.AWSInstance.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
        action=/usr/local/bin/update_stack.sh
        runas=root
    mode: '000400'
    owner: root
    group: root
```

update_stack script has parameter which value is replace with the one I can set up in CF parameter section:

```
Parameter:
  SoftwareVersion:
    Description: Software version
    Type: String
```

The script is like:

```
#!/bin/bash
...
SOFTWARE_VERSION=${SoftwareVersion}
...
```

Also in the *files* section within *AWS::CloudFormation::Init:*

The first time I run the template that value is replace by said the v1 version. When I tried to update the stack using the same template but changing the version for v2 I can see the value has change in CF console but the file remain immutable int he instance. The CF console shows the parameter with the new value, but this value will never end in the instance.

And I can see how the cfn-hup daemon is up and running and checking for changes in the metadata server, but never found any.

So my doubt: is the update process only for managing AWS resources, like ami types or security groups? or there's some trick to make that changes in the parameters available in the scripts I write in *files* within *AWS::CloudFormation::Init:*

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I reply to myself!

UserData script is only launch when the instance is created and never more. I can make changes to the script but not executed it again and I can detect changes in metadata thanks to cfn-hup daemon. So, what I did was change the software version in UserData script (/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001) and configure cfn-hup like this:

```
[cfn-auto-reloader-hook]
triggers=post.update
path=Resources.MyServer.Metadata.AWS::CloudFormation::Init
action=/usr/local/bin/update_stack.sh
runas=root
```

That script in `action` will recover the software version from UserData script and will trigger the update process of the stack.

In UserData script (in the CloudFormation template) there is a line like:

`SOFTWARE_VERSION=${SoftwareVersion}`

which is replace by the user from the CloudFormation dashboard during the update process.

Cheers!